# PHP - embed a json in a specific field inside another JSON not knowing the position of the field

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to develop a rest api that returns a json containing the requested resource. This is an example call:
GET /Posts
This is what the answer should look like:

```
[
    {
        "ID":"1",
        "desc":"Bel post fra",
        "evaluation":"2",
        "Users":{
            "id":"1",
            "imgPath":"defaultICO.png",
            "email":"e@e.com",
            "psw":"d",
            "pswSalt":"d",
            "birthDate":"2004-12-02",
            "actCode":"0",
            "actState":"0"
        },
        "Seasons":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Prova Stagione",
            "desc":"prova desc stagione",
            "imagePath":null,
            "Genres":{
                "id":"1",
                "desc":"Horror",
                "icoPath":null
            }
        },
        "Episodes":{
            "id":null,
            "ssn":null,
            "name":null,
            "desc":null,
            "relaseDate":null
        },
        "Productions":{
            "id":null,
            "name":null,
            "desc":null,
            "photoPath":null,
            "relaseYear":null,
            "gne":null,
            "sga":null
        }
        
   }
]
```

Currently I managed to create the external part of the JSON thus wrapping in the json all the relationships of the resource and the resource itself like this:

```
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      "desc":"Bel post fra",
      "evaluation":"2",
      "Users":{
         "id":"1",
         "imgPath":"defaultICO.png",
         "email":"e@e.com",
         "psw":"d",
         "pswSalt":"d",
         "birthDate":"2004-12-02",
         "actCode":"0",
         "actState":"0"
      },
      "Seasons":{
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Prova Stagione",
         "desc":"prova desc stagione",
         "imagePath":null,
        "ssn_gne_id": 1
      },
      "Episodes":{
         "id":null,
         "ssn":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "relaseDate":null
      },
      "Productions":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "photoPath":null,
         "relaseYear":null,
         "gne":null,
         "sga":null
      }
     
   }
]
```

Now I also have another array that contains all external relations and it's `$subRes`, like this:

```
"Genres":{
     "id":"1",
     "desc":"Horror",
     "icoPath":null
}
```

With this function I'm trying to merge the second array with the first in the right field, ie, in this case ssn_gne_id, I'm helping myself with this array:

```
$this->tablesStructures["Seasons"] = array("_fkField0" => "ssn_gne_id", "_fkTableField0" => "gne_id", "_FKTableName0" => "Genres", "_TableName0" => "Seasons");
$this->tablesStructures["Posts"] = array(
     "_fkField0" => "pst_usr_id",
     "_fkTableField0" => "usr_id",
     "_FKTableName0" => "Users",
     "_TableName0" => "Posts",
     "_fkField1" => "pst_ssn_id",
     "_fkTableField1" => "ssn_id",
     "_FKTableName1" => "Seasons",
     "_TableName1" => "Posts",
     "_fkField2" => "pst_epd_id",
     "_fkTableField2" => "epd_id",
     "_FKTableName2" => "Episodes",
     "_TableName2" => "Posts",
     "_fkField3" => "pst_pdc_id",
     "_fkTableField3" => "pdc_id",
     "_FKTableName3" => "Productions",
     "_TableName3" => "Posts",
     "_fkField4" => "ssn_gne_id",
     "_fkTableField4" => "gne_id",
     "_FKTableName4" => "Genres",
     "_TableName4" => "Seasons"
 );
```

This is how I use the array in question:

`_fkField` -> the name of the foreign key in table `_TableName`

`_fkTableField` -> the name of the field of the table to which `_fkField` is related

`_FKTableName` -> the name of the table where the `_fkTableField` field is present

`_TableName` -> the name of the table where the `_fkField` field is present

This is the function I was trying to program that I thought would fix the array merging problem but it doesn't work and I can't figure out what I'm missing:

```
function mergeSubResources($data, $subRes, $tablesStructures, $res)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $data[$key] = $this->mergeSubResources($value, $subRes, $tablesStructures, $res);
        } else { // Se non è un array, è un campo quindi controllo se è una foreign key esterna
            $numberOfField = $this->getNumberFromField($res, $value);
    
            if (
                $tablesStructures[$res]["_TableName" . $numberOfField] != $res &&
                $tablesStructures[$res]["_FKTableName" . $numberOfField] != $res
            ) {
                $externalTable = $tablesStructures[$res]["_FKTableName" . $numberOfField];
                $externalField = $tablesStructures[$res]["_fkField" . $numberOfField];
                $fkTableField = $tablesStructures[$res]["_fkTableField" . $numberOfField];
    
                if (isset($subRes[$externalTable]) && isset($subRes[$externalTable][$externalField])) {
                    $data[$key] = $subRes[$externalTable][$externalField][$fkTableField];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $data;
}
```

So how can I correct this function so that it merges the `subRes` arrays with my starting array in the fields provided by `tablesStructures` where that field is an external foreign key, i.e. when `_TableName` and `_FKTableName` are different from the main resource?

Comment: Elements named with plurals like `Users` and `Seasons` seem like they should contain arrays of object, not just a single object.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I know it should be Season, and then User etc in the main array but I have yet to fix that

Comment: @Barmar That shouldn't be the cause of the problem though, right?

Comment: No, although it might mean that the solution you come up for this won't work when you change them to arrays.

Comment: Which objects correspond to each parameter of the merge function?

Comment: Keys like `"_fkField4"` and `"_fkTableField4"` suggest that you should be using nested arrays there, rather than separate keys, e.g. `tableStructures["Posts"] = [["fkField" => "pst_user_id", "fkTableField" => "usr_id", ...], ...]`

Comment: @Barmar $data is the full associative array so it would be the full json in array though. $subRes is an associative array which contains the resources which should match the foreign keys, in that case Genres must match snn_gne_id, $res is the main resource which the client wants to get so it would be Posts

Comment: You have 4 parameters to the function, but you've only shown 3 sample inputs in the question.

Comment: @Barmar yes then there is $tablesStructures which represents the direct and indirect relationships with the other tables with respect to the main resource

Comment: That's one of the 3 you showed: `$this->tablesStructures["Seasons"] = ...`

Comment: Do I understand correctly?  `"_fkField4" => "ssn_gne_id",` and `"_FKTableName4" => "Genres"` tells it that `"ssn_gne_id": 1` should be replaced with that `$subRes`, because it has the key `"Genres"`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes because for now I'm making calls only on Seasons and Posts just for debug so I didn't declare other resources in that array: As you can see, Posts has an indirect relationship and all the others are direct, while Seasons has only direct relationships

Comment: I still don't see where you defined `$res`. The first thing you showed is the desired result. Then you showed `$data`, then `$subRes`, then `$tableStructures`.

Comment: @Barmar $res is just a variable that is passed to the merging function that has a string value that represents the resource that the client made the request for. In this case:
Get /Posts
$res will have the value "Posts"

Comment: @Barmar exactly "_fkField4" => "ssn_gne_id", and "_FKTableName4" => "Genres" tells it that "ssn_gne_id": 1 need to be replaced with that $subRes because it has the key "Genres"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253612/discussion-between-barmar-and-conta).